# CRON Expression on Azure function

Tags: c#, cron, azure-functions

I am trying to run my azure function based on time using CRON to run every minute between 8PM till 3 AM the next day.
using this

`0 */1 20-23,0-3 * * *`

But it is not working, any idea what the expression should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Actually that expression worked.
Azure function use CRONTAB expression and to do so you can use this website to create your expression

https://crontab.guru/

Answer (score 0):

you ned to create two separate functions with identical code but diff expressions:

1. For 8 pm to 11:59pm: `0 * 20-23 ***`
2. For 12 am to 3am: `0 * 0-3 ***`